# Leetcode - Defanging IP address

Tags: c++, string

I am doing the [IP defanging challenge](https://leetcode.com/problems/defanging-an-ip-address/) on Leetcode using C++. The following is my attempt at the solution:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address) {
        for(int i = 0; i < address.size(); i++){
            if(address[i] == '.'){
                address.replace(i, 1, "[.]");
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
};
```

Here, the code is not able to replace the period with `"[.]"`, it returns "Time Limit Exceeded" instead.

I tried replacing it with `"[]"` and it works fine, and so does it for every other possible string combination. I tried escaping, but even that doesn't work.

Is `"[.]"` some special string that cannot be read? I do know there is a solution where you concatenate strings iteratively, but shouldn't this work too?

Answer (score 3):

When the loop encounters the first `.`, it replaces the `.` with `[.]`, thus increasing the string's `size`.  But the loop is not adjusting `i` to account for the newly inserted `[`, so the next iteration will see the same `.` after that new `[` and perform the same replacement again, and again, and again, endlessly.  That is why your solution is timing out.

You need to make sure you are advancing `i` past the replacement text, eg:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address) {
        for(string::size_type i = 0; i < address.size(); ++i){
            if (address[i] == '.'){
                address.replace(i, 1, "[.]");
                i += 2; // <-- skip to ']', the subsequent ++i will then skip past it
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/6FWVGh)

Alternatively, use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, then you can decide more easily how much to increment `i` each time:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address) {
        string::size_type i = 0;
        while (i < address.size()){
            if (address[i] == '.'){
                address.replace(i, 1, "[.]");
                i += 3;
            }
            else {
                ++i;
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/PkqSIw)

Personally, I would use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) in the loop instead, eg:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address) {
        string::size_type i = 0;
        while ((i = address.find('.', i)) != string::npos){
            address.replace(i, 1, "[.]");
            i += 3;
        }
        return address;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/EnW1Dy)

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed the increment. Thanks for the alternate, first time hearing about find(), will definitely be using it more.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a sample input, `bo.y`. When `i` is 2, `replace` turns the string to `bo[.]y`. Then, when `i` is 3, it sees that pesky `.` again, and `replace` turns it to `bo[[.]]y`. This keeps happening until it times out.

The fix? increment i after you call replace:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address) {
        for(int i = 0; i < address.size(); i++){
            if(address[i] == '.'){
                address.replace(i, 1, "[.]");
                i++;
            }
        }
        return address;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65311861/10871073), your problem lies in the fact that the loop counter never gets past the 'new' `'.'` character when you increase the string's length.

Although that answer is, in itself, faultless, I find that it is often *far* simpler, in *any* string replacement and/or substitution operation, to avoid trying to do the work 'inline'; rather, it is most often much easier to make a copy, replacing the copied parts as and when necessary:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    string defangIPaddr(string address)
    {
        string answer{ "" }; // Local string to build the answer - start off empty.
        answer.reserve(address.size() * 2); // Reserve sufficient space to avoid multiple reallocation.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < address.size(); i++) {
            if (address[i] == '.') {
                answer += "[.]"; // For a dot, replace with the "[.]" string ...
            }
            else {
                answer += address[i]; // ... otherwsie, just copy the character.
            }
        }
        answer.shrink_to_fit(); // Free any unneeded memory.
        return answer; // We return BY VALUE, so a copy is made of the LOCAL "answer".
    }
};
```

Comment: If you are going to take this approach, you should at least `reserve()` the `answer` to reduce the number of memory reallocations that `operator+=` will have to perform.  Otherwise, use a `std::ostringstream` to gather the new characters, and then convert that to a `std::string` when finished.

Comment: @Remy Fair point (see edit). (Although, it appears that clang-cl gives the new string a capacity of 15 by default, increasing that, no doubt, in chunks of 16.)